# PowerShell to send email

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am running a Task Scheduler to execute my PowerShell every 30 minutes.

So

> $users = Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -SearchBase
>   "OU=People,DC=Example,DC=com" -SearchScope Subtree | Select
>   SamAccountName

This returns a list of users. Now I want to create an emailbody with the users

```
$EmailBody = ForEach($user in $users) {"`r`n",$user}



Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject "Locked Accounts" -BodyAsHtml $EmailBody -From $from -Credential $cred -SmtpServer $server -Debug
```

However my current code will send the email even if NO ONE is locked. Is there anyway I can check to see if the $users has at least 1 person?

(I haven't tested the $EmailBody but would like to know if this is acceptable for BodyAsHtml)

================

Updated Code

```
if ($users)    {
    if ($users.count -gt 0) {#even if there are users, this line always is false. 
        # send the email here
        foreach($user in $users)
        {
            $message = $message + " " + $user + " is locked out" + "`r`n"
            Write-Host $user
        }
        Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject "Locked Accounts" -BodyAsHtml $message -From $from -Credential $cred -SmtpServer $server -Debug        
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($users -ne $null)   # lists can be empty as well, in which case the count fails
{
    if ($users.count -gt 0) {
        # send the email here
    }
}
```

Comment: Error on line 1 -ne null

Comment: null should probably be $null

Comment: anyways I changed the code to if($users) because if its not null its true then it moves to the next line. However when $users.count executes, the condition is always false even when there are users in the list. I think that maybe it's an array or a dictionary. What do you think?

Comment: What does it output when you just do a $users.count? A number, or something else? If it's an array the .Count property should work. You can also do a `$users | get-member` to figure out what the type is.

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised if $users.Length was needed instead. That said, generally answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)